# Limit http network traffic to only images

Tags: android, http, mobile

I have a question regarding networking traffic delimitation, especially HTTP. I want to be able to delimit HTTP traffic to only accept .png, .jpeg, or any other image variation.
i.e https://www.privateislandsonline.com/uploads/245/image_d05d567275.jpg == VALID

i.e https://www.privateislandsonline.com == NOT VALID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow HTTP traffic from a specific domain you just have to add the following:

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

res/xml/network_security_config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">MY.DOMAIN.COM</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Now you can start receiving HTTP traffic from that domain only

Answer (score 0):

use nginx location to match image URI pattner like below

```
http {
    location ~* /.*\.(gif|png|jpeg)${
        root /data/img/;
    }

    location / {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Comment: mmm I thought that this could be done in the ```manifest.xml``` file, and where do I have to add this pattern that you implemented?

Comment: i'm not sure what's mainfest.xml you saying about. But the config I wrote is nginx configuration and which is an  reverse proxy web server you can work with.  checkout https://www.nginx.com/ for more information.